# How to use passportjs to authenticate users in a meteor database without meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm planning to write a separate API to my meteor app which can be used to connect mobile apps and some other third party systems. I currently use the react native meteor plugin to directly connect the meteor app. But we need to de-couple the mobile app from meteor. To do this, I'm going to create a separate API connecting directly to the database. So, I will have access to the old user accounts create by Meteor. Can I use the same accounts to authenticate users through passport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you have the username and password, you can use the Accounts package by encrypting the given password and then comparing it to the user's stored password. Here's how you would do that in Meteor with npm packages.

```
function authenticateUser(username, password){
    //encrypting password
    var bcrypt = Package['npm-bcrypt'].NpmModuleBcrypt;
    var SHA256 = Package.sha.SHA256;
    var hashedPass= SHA256(password);
    var bcryptHash = Meteor.wrapAsync(bcrypt.hash);
    hashedPass = bcryptHash(hashedPass, 10);
    //current password
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username:username})
    if (user) {
        var pass = user.services.password.bcrypt;
        return pass === hashedPass;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How to do it without using any meteor packages or methods?

Comment: Find the libraries that do SHA256 and bcrypt (in whatever language or framework you are using for the external api) and use them to encode the password as in my example. I am using the npm modules here. If you are asking about building an external API, you can use an api_key and api_secret to connect directly to the db to get the user's info. We have built one in Elixir language.